# Obtaining user's amount in change

Tags: java

I have to create a java program (without the use of if statements) where the user inputs a number and I have to output their number in the form of coins:

```
import java.io.*;
public class ModQuestions
public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));

System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
String s = buffer.readLine();
int n = Integer.parseInt(s);

System.out.println ("That is " + (n / 200) + " toonies.");
n = n % 200;
System.out.println ("That is " + (n / 100) + " loonies.");
n = n % 100;
System.out.println ("That is " + (n / 25) + " quarters.");
n = n % 25;
System.out.println ("That is " + (n / 10) + " dimes.");
n = n % 10;
System.out.println ("That is " + (n / 5) + " nickels.");
n = n % 5;
System.out.println ("That is " + (n) + " pennies.");
```

I have this so far, but now I have to alter my code so that if the answer is 0 (for example, that is 0 toonies) I don't want to print that line at all. Also, If the output is "That is 1 Toonies" I have to make it say "That is 1 toonie." I've been trying to figure out how to do this without the use of if statements so if anyone can help, it'd be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Use an if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

One way to use conditions in Java without requiring an if statement is to use Java's *ternary operator*, '?'.

This acts as a true/false switch, for example:

```
int three = 3;
System.out.println((three > 2) ? "greater" : "less");
```

Will print

```
greater
```

as it acts as *`condition ? true : false`*

In your example, use it to check if 'toonies' is greater than 1 and then print either 'toonies' if true, or 'toonie' if false.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a decision structure, and don't want to use if's, use `for` loops and define the details of each coin:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModQuestions {

     public static void main(String []args){

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        // coinTypes contain the number to be divided for, singular and plural names for each type of coin
        String[][] coinTypes = {{"200", "toony", "toonies"}, {"100", "loony", "loonies"}, {"25", "quarter", "quarters"}, {"10", "dime", "dimes"}, {"5", "nickel", "nickels"}, {"1", "penny", "pennies"}};

        for(String[] coin : coinTypes) {
            int convertedCoin = (n / Integer.parseInt(coin[0]));

            if(convertedCoin > 0) // this is just to check if the value is higher then 0, if not, nothing is printed
            System.out.println("That is " + convertedCoin + " " + (convertedCoin > 1 ? coin[2] : coin[1]));
        }
     }
}
```

Working example [here](https://repl.it/@tomrlh/IntentionalWoodenStacks).

Answer (score 0):

You have to manipulate the condition per your requirement. You have to change your `if` conditions to catch all your required conditions and edit the response according to that.

Sample scenario can be identified as below.

```
if (n/200 > 0) { // Only continue if there is a chance to represent the amount in `toonies (unit 200s)`
    if(n/200 == 1) { // is only one `toonie` required ?
        System.out.println ("That is " + (n / 200) + " toonie.");
    } else { // more than one `toonie` is required
        System.out.println ("That is " + (n / 200) + " toonies.");
    }
    n = n % 200; // to change `n` to the remainder
} else if (n/100 > 0) {
    .......
} .......
```